# create 'uploads' folder in root path of repo in production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In my development server, I have written a code to create a folder called `uploads/` where routes and controller folders exist. But when I push code to the server in production, it throws an error to create that folder:

> Error creating uploads folder: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/anofy/dist/anomalify-server/uploads

```js
const folderName = "uploads";
const folderPath = path.join(__dirname, folderName);


     fs.stat(folderPath, (err, stats) => {
    if (err) {
      // Folder doesn't exist, create it
      if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
        fs.mkdir(folderPath, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error("Error creating uploads folder:", err);
          } else {
            console.log("Uploads folder created successfully.");
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.error("Error checking uploads folder:", err);
      }
    } else {
      // Folder exists
      console.log("Uploads folder already exists.");`your text`
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The user running the node.js process on the production server does not have write permissions in the /home/ubuntu/anofy/dist/anomalify-server/ directory to create the 'uploads' folder.

To resolve this you will need to grant write permissions to the '/home/ubuntu/anofy/dist/anomalify-server/' directory so that the Node.JS process can create the 'uploads' folder.

So you need to find out which user runs this Node.js process. Once you find out, replace $user$ with the user in the bash commands below:

**1. Changes ownership to the user running the Node.js process**
$ chown -R $user$ /home/ubuntu/anofy/dist/anomalify-server

**2. Adds write permissions for the user running the Node.js process in the directory and its subdirectories:**
$ chmod u+w -R /home/ubuntu/anofy/dist/anomalify-server